# Getting the html source of selected text from context menue in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selection

I am trying to get to the html source of a selected text from a click on the context action in a google chrome extension (getting the highlighted text itself is not what I am looking for).

The following background script (coffee source) tries to get to the selection object (as an intermediate step) by `executeScript` and `sendRequest`. However, `selection` and `response` are 
undefined. Why does it fail and what is the correct way to proceed?

```
logSelectionViaExecuteScript= ->
  chrome.tabs.executeScript
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();" , (selection) ->
      console.log 
        name: 'logSelectionViaExecuteScript'
        selection: selection

logSelectionViaSendRequestThroughTabs= (tabId)->
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest tabId, {method: "getSelection"}, (response)->
    console.log 
      name: 'logSelectionViaSendRequestThroughTabs'
      tabId: tabId
      response: response

onClickAction= (info, tab)->
  console.log  info: info
  console.log  tab: tab 
  logSelectionViaSendRequestThroughTabs(tab.id)
  logSelectionViaExecuteScript()

chrome.contextMenus.create
  title:"Highlight '%s'"
  contexts: ["selection"]
  onclick: onClickAction
```

I am aware that some of the functions are deprecated. However, they should still work as I understand the documentation.

**Edit:**

The example on Github has been deleted since the problem is resolved.

Comment: What do you mean the html source of a selected text? Are you looking for the modifying html tags, like <b>,<i>,<span> if the selected text contains some of them, or you are looking for the most inner html element that contains the selected text entirely? Can you provide some example maybe?

Comment: In the end, I wish to modify the elements in the dom which correspond to the selected text. I also want to 'remember' the selected html.

Comment: Please post enough code for a potential answerer to reproduce your environment. E.g., manifest.json and the rest (if any) of the background page. It would also be helpful to write in JavaScript so that others can run the code without getting a CoffeeScript translator.

Comment: I provided a complete example as requested. See **Edit** in the description.

Comment: What do you even expect from `sendRequest` if nothing listens to it?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the API description. Here is an outline how it works:

In the background script:

```
logSelectionViaSendMessageThroughTabs= (tabId)->
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage  tabId, {method: "getSelection"}, (response)->
    console.log 
      name: 'logSelectionViaSendMessageThroughTabs'
      tabId: tabId
      response: response
```

Note the use of `sendMessage`, which is the non deprecated function to use.

Here is the snippet from the content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (message,sender,sendResponse)->
  if message.method is "getSelection" 
    selection= window.getSelection()
    # do something with selection and send it off with sendResponse
```